# "conda update --all" fails due to missing files

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I try to update all my packeges using `conda update --all` the command seems to be abble to succesfully collect all the packages, but then this error occurs (apologies for the long copy-paste):

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 76, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Menu\\spyder_shortcut.json'menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 76, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Menu\\spyder_shortcut.json'menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 76, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.json'menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 76, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.json'DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\anaconda-navigator-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\anaconda-navigator-script.py']
\ WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\Library\resources\icudtl.dat.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4'.
Rolling back transaction: |
```

I've searched online but could not find any solution. I think this is related to the reason why the commands `conda update python` and `conda update spyder` fail.

I also tried running this as Adminiwstrator, but didn't help

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I'm getting the same problem, with the fun addition of `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Menu\\spyder_shortcut.jsodone` on a later line. The string isn't finished on that additional error, which makes me think something is triggering an internal error with the way the package manager is handling strings.

I found a similar issue on GitHub (https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11524), where someone said to uninstall and reinstall the entirety of Anaconda.